# Ubuntu 20 stopping MySQL for automatic update

Tags: server, updates, mysql, dovecot

I have Dovecot server with MySQL. Ubuntu is stopping MySQL automatically which causes problems in Dovecot.

Why does this happen? How to disable auto update on MySQL or Ubuntu server?

Logs:

```
Mar  8 06:36:09 mail-ag-br1-9 systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.3.32 database server...
Mar  8 06:36:11 mail-ag-br1-9 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Succeeded.
Mar  8 06:36:11 mail-ag-br1-9 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.3.32 database server.
Mar  8 06:36:12 mail-ag-br1-9 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar  8 06:36:17 mail-ag-br1-9 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.34 database server...
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.34 database server.
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 /etc/mysql/debian-start[169719]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 /etc/mysql/debian-start[169722]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 /etc/mysql/debian-start[169722]: Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 /etc/mysql/debian-start[169722]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 /etc/mysql/debian-start[169722]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 /etc/mysql/debian-start[169728]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Mar  8 06:36:18 mail-ag-br1-9 debian-start[169731]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Dovecot problem:

```
Mar  8 06:36:20 mail-ag-br1-9 dovecot: auth-worker(3808425): Error: sql(****@*****,127.0.0.1,<pxmptrHZrKB/AAAB>): Password query failed: Connection was killed
```

Ty.

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu Core 20? Likely not. Please [edit] to correct it.

Comment: The database upgrade failed, which points to something in the database files that is either corrupt or modified in a suboptimal manner. You can certainly disable updates to MariaDB by pinning the version in apt, but it may be better to first resolve the reason for the upgrade failure 